# What are the similarities between Spring and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-boot

I have a requirement that I have to use Spring Boot with JSF as user interface, as of now I am using JSF with spring other modules. So, I want know the similarities, differences and advantages of Spring boot over Spring other modules.

Comment: You cannot compare Spring Boot and Spring Framework. Spring boot uses Spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, Spring Boot is highly opinionated wrapper for Spring Framework with a lot of production and cloud ready features. It can significantly reduce amount of your configuration if you follow conventions.

[Start reading here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-introducing-spring-boot).

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare spring boot and spring framework. Spring Boot is a new project aims to help spring development by auto configuration of things required to run the spring application.

So, if you have spring application, you can use spring boot to run your Spring application without worrying about writing the XML configuration.